# Is it possible to use AdMob Unity Plugin with CustomEvent?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I'd like to perform mediation with the AdMob Unity plugin.
But I couldn't find any way to perform mediation with Custom Event.
Is it possible?

see also: [googleads-mobile-unity](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/tree/master/source), [AdMob mediation support](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation)